# material ui Tabs unclickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Tabs from material-ui are unclickable. Nothing happens then i click on them.
Code is just simple:

```
 `var Tabs = React.createClass ({
   render: function() { 
    return (
        <Tabs>
            <Tab label="1">
              <p>hello 1</p>
            </Tab>
            <Tab label="2"/>
              <p>hello 2</p>
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    );
   }
  });`
```

But on the page i see theese tabs with first tab opened and then i click on the second nothing happens. Tried different browsers. What could go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add this code:

```
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

I wonder why it is not explicitly mentioned in their examples.

Comment: There's a mention on the [installation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation) page.

Comment: Yes, noticed after some time ... Classic rtfm scenario

Comment: To their credit, they have been constantly evolving their documentation, a good part of their commits. This wasn't much of an issue previously when the documentation was "simpler" (they only had most important stuff up there :)). As the content has grown, some responsibility has now been shifted to the reader. Maybe if they add a Troubleshooting section to the site, folks would look there first as this seems to be a genuinely common issue with the library users.

Comment: I have the same issue. Tabs are navigable by keyboard but not by mouse ever since I updated to version 15.2 of Material-UI. I have injected the plugin as shown above but to no avail.